# \ufeff Invalid character in identifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, urllib, python-3.3

I have the following code :

```
import urllib.request

try:
    url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=test"

    headers = {}
    usag = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0'
    headers['User-Agent'] = usag.encode('utf-8-sig')
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respData = resp.read()

    saveFile = open('withHeaders.txt','w')
    saveFile.write(str(respData))
    saveFile.close()

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

it gives me the following error:

```
D:\virtualenv\samples\urllibb>python 1.py
  File "1.py", line 35
    usag = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0'\ufeff
                                                                                              ^
 SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

I can't see the `\ufeff` in my code though.

Comment: I missed that you used an image for the error. It is text, just copy and paste it here, that makes your error searchable (always a good idea).

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't copy from CMD... (or maybe I'm Noob enough)

Comment: Use the `[-]` menu on your CMD window, it has options there to select and copy.

Answer (score 18):

`\ufeff` is a the [*ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE* codepoint](https://codepoints.net/U+FEFF); it is not rendered when printing. It is used as a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in UTF-16 and UTF-32 to record the order in which the encoded bytes are to be decoded (big-endian or little-endian).

UTF-8 doesn't need a BOM (it only has one fixed ordering of the bytes, no need to track an alternative), but Microsoft decided it was a handy *signature* character for their tools to detect UTF-8 files vs. 8-bit encodings (such as most of the windows codepages employ).

I suspect you are using a Microsoft text editor such as Notepad to save your code. Don't do this, it'll include the BOM but Python doesn't support it or strip it from UTF-8 source files. You probably saved the file with Notepad, then continued with a different tool to add more code to the start and the BOM got caught in the middle.

Either delete the whole line and the next and re-type them, or select from the closing quote of the string you define until just before the `h` of `headers` on the next line, delete that part and re-insert a newline and enough indentation.

If your editor supports using escape sequences when searching and replacing (SublimeText does when in regex mode, for example), you could just use *that* to search for the character and replace it with an empty string. In SublimeText, switch on regex support and search for `\x{feff}`, replacing those occurrences with an empty string.

The Python `utf-8-sig` encoding that you are using here also includes that BOM:

```
headers['User-Agent'] = usag.encode('utf-8-sig')
```

HTTP headers should **not** include that codepoint either. HTTP headers typically stick to Latin-1 instead; even ASCII would suffice here, but otherwise use `'utf-8'` (no `-sig`).

You don't really need to use `str.encode()` there, you could *also* just define a bytestring:

```
headers = {}
usag = b'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0'
headers['User-Agent'] = usag
```

Note the `b` prefix to the string literal.

Comment: hmm, doesn't work either :( http://i.imgur.com/J1zjdwF.jpg
By the way I'm using sublime on Windows 7.

Comment: @Katallone: the character is still there, yes. It is really part of your file. The remark about using a byte string literal is *extra*, it was not meant to be a fix for that character being there. You still need to fix that, but once that is done, *then* you also need to fix the `utf-8-sig` problem, and the best way to do that is to just define your bytestring as a literal instead of encoding it.

Comment: @Katallone what do you think I've been trying to do here? What did you want me to do, come over to your place and edit the file for you? I've given you *several* methods to try out. Just complaining that they don't work doesn't tell me anything. I can't see your screen or see what you are doing right or wrong. Take into account that we volunteer our time, this is not my job. Sorry this isn't working for you but, really, tone down that sense of entitlement a little, please.

Answer (score 7):

simply, open script file in Notepad++, go to the "Encoding" tab, select "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM" and save file.

Answer (score 0):

For *nix folk, just open the file with

```
[n]vim -b filename
```

then

```
:set list
```

You'll see it at the begging of the fist line. Since it's zero width you cant even delete it in text mode, tried deleting the line and pasting in the text from having stripped it out in python and it was still there before character 0 in text.

Answer (score 0):

In the most upvoted answer, they recommended using regex search/replace in Sublime Text to replace the characters.  I couldn't get that to work but if you simply "Save with Encoding" and choose UTF-8 instead of UTF-8 with BOM it will do what you need.[image]

Answer (score -1):

The character is there, after the closing quote on the `usag = 'Mozilla...` line.

Comment: But they can't *see* it, presumably in their editor. That's because it is an invisible zero-width character.