# Pandas dataframe from csv file has weird characters in the nane of first column

Tags: python, pandas, google-drive-api

I have the following method that loads data from a CSV file stored in Google drive:

```
def load(self):
    filename = 'temp_{}.csv'.format(uuid1())
    self.driver.download_file(self.file_id, filename)
    try:
        data = LocalCsvHandler(
            filename, self.delimiter, self.encoding,self.skipinitialspace).load()
            os.remove(filename)
    except UnicodeDecodeError as error:
        os.remove(filename)

        raise error

        return data


class LocalCsvHandler:
    def __init__(self, filename, delimiter, encoding, skipinitialspace=None):
        self.filename = filename
        self.delimiter = delimiter
        self.encoding = encoding
        self.skipinitialspace = skipinitialspace

    def load(self):
        data = []
        with open(self.filename, encoding=self.encoding) as csvfile:
            csvreader = DictReader(
                csvfile, delimiter=self.delimiter,
                skipinitialspace=self.skipinitialspace)
            for row in csvreader:
                data.append(row)

        return data
```

After loaded, I generate a Pandas DataFramework with de ordered dict obtained from that previous method:

```
def _dataframe_from_ordered_dict(self, source_data: List[OrderedDict]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Genreates a Pandas DataFrame in case data loades as OrderdDict

    Args:
        source_data (List[OrderedDict]): Data loaded

    Returns:
        pd.DataFrame: Pandas DataFrame
    """

    return pd.DataFrame([source_data[i] for i, j in enumerate(source_data)])
```

The problem is that when I list the names of the columns of the DataFrame, I get this list:

`['\ufeffzipcode', 'primary_city','state']`

As you can see, the name of the first column has some extra characters, so I can't reference it by its name.

How can I avoid loading the data with these characters?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35070677/ufeff-invalid-character-in-identifier

Comment: Why not just use pandas `read_csv` instead of your intermediate conversion that appears to gain you nothing but bugs?

Comment: @CJR To make it reusable, not al cases come from a csv file